# Did native americans ever used the practice of a "Rain Dance" in order to encourage rains?

Tags: anthropology

In popular culture there is a claim that Native American used a ritual dance in order to encourage rains.

For example, in the *How I Met Your Mother* episode ["Come On"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Come_On_%28How_I_Met_Your_Mother%29) Ted does a rain dance in order to make rain fall ([video clip](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=idzIGOCrtV0)).

[Tim Minchin uses rain dancing](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pQjqxayxwt4) to explain logic fallacies.

Is there any truth to it? Did Native Americans perform a dancing ritual whose purpose was to encourage more rains or to stop droughts?

Comment: The video in this post has been removed, but you can still find online here: https://www.dailymotion.com/video/x2mx2l6

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes. See: http://www.indians.org/articles/rain-dance.html

> This rain dance was meant to bring rain for the entire year or for a specific season.

Other main points:

- Usually in late August
- Still performed today
- Special clothing made just for the rain dances
- More common in Native American tribes in the dry, Southwestern United States

Elsie Clews Parsons. *Some Aztec and Pueblo Parallels*. American Anthropologist , New Series, Vol. 35, No. 4 (Oct. - Dec., 1933), pp. 611-631

> In an Aztec rain dance held every eight years [...]
>
> It was the Aztec belief that in this rain ceremony all the gods were dancing, and therefore the dancers were dressed in diverse fancy costume [...]

Gertrude P. Kurath. *Calling the Rain Gods*. The Journal of American Folklore , Vol. 73, No. 290 (Oct. - Dec., 1960), pp. 312-316

> In winter and spring [the rain gods] are also called in unmasked rain dances by men.

The dance is described:

> To lure the rain gods and clouds he beckons with a circling of the wrist